# Cakephp ajax issue on update

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp-2.8

I am facing a problem when a try to submit a form data to edit using ajax. when I debug() $this->request->data I get an empty array().
My form is in a modal window, that shows up when the user clicks in a edit button.
NB: When is a non ajax way it works well.

My controller method:

```
public function editarModal() {
        debug($this->request->data); // This value is empty when I use ajax
        if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
            debug($this->RequestHandler->isAjax());
            if($this->Concurso->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->render('sucesso', 'ajax'); // returns a message to the user
            } else {
                $this->render('erro', 'ajax');
            }
        } else {
            if($this->Concurso->save($this->request->data)) {
                //$this->Flash->success('Dados submetidos com exito!');
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope you can give me an idea of why I’m receiving  this empty array(),
Thanks in advance!

Comment: post your form and ajax code as well...